How to import stripe subscription to a new site?
I have a site that has a old version of civi 5.35, and decided to upgrade. But ran into isuue and DB corrupted, so decided to do a fresh install of latest LTS of CiviCRM 5.74.5 and import all contacts and payments.
All went fine except the stripe recurring payments are not coming thru to the new site.
I have also updated the recurring records in latest site. When I resent the webhook from stripe dashboard to the new site I receive response
Response
HTTP status code
200 (OK)
Event (evt_1Pv4BrxrhfuR3SMOClX) is not for this payment processor - ignoring. CiviCRM: Stripe (Live).

I can see from my stripe dashboard, it is using 2 different API version simultaneously.
Is that the problem, that payments were created with different API version?
Anyone has any idea what is wrong and how to fix this please? Thanks

Are the payment processor ids the same as on the old site? e.g. if the live processor used to be id 1, is it also id 1 in the new site?

@Demerit IDs are different

Then that sounds like the problem. Can you make them the same - it might be as easy as switching the values of is_test in the db.

@Demerit tried that, still same message in webhook.
